# What does 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' ' mean?

Tags: function, memory, vector, memory-leaks, ifstream

I'm writing a function that opens a text file and reads each line, adding it to a vector of strings(each line is just one word). The code compiles but terminates with an error when I try to run it.

Here is the error I'm getting after calling the function and attempting to print the vector:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

If I call the function but don't print the vector I get a `Segmentation Fault`

I looked up this error online, but I couldn't find any exact definitions of what it means. From what I saw it seems that this error is thrown in relation to using too much memory. Maybe there is something in my code that is causing an infinite loop?? What exactly does this error mean, and how does it apply to the code I've written?

```
 vector<string> readToVector(string fileTo) {
        vector<string> setVector;
        string temp;
        ifstream openSet(fileTo.c_str());
        if (openSet.is_open()) {
            while ( getline (openSet,temp) ) {
                    setVector.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Unable to open set file." << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I am stupid. I just never returned the vector in my function. *facepalm*